Validate passed props according to passed component
I have a Tabs component that looks like this:
const tabs = [{
  component: Component1,
  props: propsToComponent1
},
{
  component: Component2,
  props: propsToComponent2
}],

<Tabs tabs={tabs} />

I need to validate the props key so the props matches the props type of the component
I've tried doing something like this
interface iTab {
  component: React.ComponentType<any>;
  props?: iTab['component']['defaultProps'],
  ...
}

interface iTabsProps {
  tabs?: Array<iTab>;
  ...
}

but its not working and I'm stuck here.

iTab must be generic, but then each item of the array should have a different generic type, which is really tricky. But there should be previous similar questions.
